# No Keyboard or Mouse with Ubuntu 18.04 Install DVD

Tags: boot, system-installation, keyboard, mouse, 18.04

Attempting to install 18.04 using DVD.  DVD boots into Ubuntu Live but neither the keyboard nor mouse work, both are completely unresponsive.  This same operation works fine for DVD with 16.04.  Keyboard is Corsair K95, mouse is Corsair M65 Pro.  Is this a defect or are Corsair products not supported in 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

Corsair and Ubuntu seems to not be friends.
With new kernel you may have more luck. Try to upgrade your OS.

And you can also install **ckb-next**

https://github.com/ckb-next/ckb-next